# Retrieving a uint64 value in a vba application running 32 bit office

Tags: c++, ms-access, vba

I have some vba coding for opening files in binary mode and storing a value to a vriable for subsequent use. I have information on the file structure (I think the files were created from a program developed in C or C++) so know the offset for the position in the file and that it's data type is Uint64 (so 8 byte).

The code snippet for this is as follows:

```
Dim strFile as String

Dim p as Long

strFile = "Testfile"

Open strFile For Binary As #1    ' Open file.

p = 1024 ' position of variable in file

Get 1, p, Value
```

The variable 'Value' needs to be declared as a VBA equivalent to Unit64 but as I'm running a 32-bit version of office I'm a bit stuck. I tried declaring as Double but this didn't return the correct value. Not sure why.

Any advice would be much appreciated

Thanks

Comment: What about VBA `Variant`?

Answer (score 0):

An array of integers will probably the best option.

```vb
Sub TestGetBin()

    Dim DataByte(0 To 7) As Byte
    Dim DataLong(0 To 1) As Long
    Dim i As Long

    ' File contains "abcdefghijklmnopq"
    Open "D:\abc.txt" For Binary As #1

    Get 1, 1, DataByte
    Get 1, 1, DataLong

    Debug.Print Hex(DataLong(0)), Hex(DataLong(1))

    For i = 0 To 7
        Debug.Print Hex(DataByte(i))
    Next i

    Close #1

End Sub
```

This yields

```
64636261      68676665

61
62
63
64
65
66
67
68
```

so you'll probably be happier with the Byte array (and create your number from it).
(Well, depends on how the number is stored. Try it out.)

Comment: Thanks Andre, that pointed me in the right direction. The value in the variable was a date stored as an integer. I retrieved each byte and then converted back to the original number. So the first read was added to the second which was multiplied by 256, this was then added to the third which was multiplied by 256^2 and so on until the 8th byte.